# How to list content from a tar file without recursion?

Tags: filesystems, gzip, tar, compression

I've a tar (gz, bzip) file and want to see its content, but not recursively.

This is: The "first level" in the file.

I already know how to see content:

tar -ztf file.tar.gz

But it's recursive!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about something like:

tar -ztf file.tar.gz | egrep '^[^/]+/?$'

Comment: Slow for large tarballs, but workable

Answer (score 20):

`tar --exclude='*/*' -tf yourarchive.tar` should do it.

That's almost certainly a GNU tar-ism. But who doesn't use GNU tar, right? (Another fun fact: in recent versions of GNU tar, you don't need the 'z' or 'j' to list or uncompress .gz or .bz files -- it autodetects those and it just works.)

Comment: Easier to understand and remember and plenty fast.

Comment: This is great, but I'll never remember that `-t` means *list*. So `-tf` can be converted to `--list -f`.

Comment: This option is much faster than the accepted answer, thank you!

Comment: To see the first level of hierarchy I used `tar --exclude='*/*/*' -tf yourarchive.tar`

Answer (score 1):

This should show top-level directories as well as just files that include the dot character:

```
$ tar -tf app.tar.gz | grep -E '^\w+(\.\w+)*/*\w+(\.\w+)*/?$'

django/
django/django.wsgi
django/search_indexes/
django/templates/
django/app/
django/other-app/
```